# DVD stuck in 2006 iMac, won't boot

Tags: imac, startup, optical-drive

So I put a DVD in and it wouldn't come out. I wanted to try the "hold left mouse during start up" method of getting it out and now it won't boot and I can still not get the DVD out. It is my GF's old iMac and I think the reason she never puts in DVD's is this. Is there any way to:

a) Get the DVD out

and

b) reboot the iMac

If I can fix a) it might be that b) is fixed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how, but after trying a number of times, he DVD finally came out while I was holding down the left mouse button during start up and after that it booted up.